# How to write dropdown menu for currentuser

Tags: drop-down-menu

I'm a noob in RoR world and I need some help.
The question is this:
I've this form

```
      <div class="form-container">
      <%= form_for([@modulo2.user, @modulo2]) do |f| %>
      ..........
      <div class="form-field">  
      <h3> Modulo1: </h3><br/>
      <%= f.select(:modulo1_id, Modulo1.all.map{|p| [p.nome_progetto]}, :prompt =>                      
                                              "Seleziona il Modulo1 associato") %>
      </div>
      </div><br/>
```

the result is a dropdown menu for all Modulo1s but I need only the ones for current_user. what can I try??? 
In adding, when I select one item from this dropdown menu I have no association from values in table.

Sorry for this question but I can't find answers searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
                <%= f.select(:modulo1_id, current_user.modulo1s.all.map{|p|            
                [p.nome_progetto,p.id]}, :prompt => "Seleziona il Modulo1 associato") %>
```

I've only one doubt, if I need an if statement with a boolean variable before this select what could I try??